# How to write AspectJ AOP expression for this method?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have tried many combinations but I am unable to invoke callback before execution of following method

```
@SomeAnnotation(...)
@Override
public void someMethod(Serializable id) {

}
```

I have tried many combinations similar to

```
@Before("execution(@com.full.name.of.SomeAnnotation  * com.full.name.of.Class.someMethod(java.io.Serializable))")
public void beforeMethod() {
    System.out.println("I am here.");
}
```

If I write a more generic expession, it hits the `beforeMethod` but I am unable to target a single specific method. What am I missing here?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please edit and tell me what you want to match. What is the "more generic expression"? Do you want to match all methods with that annotation? Something else? Do you need to bind the annotation to a parameter in order to access its parameters? I do not like to guess, so please clarify. Then I will be easily able to help you.

Comment: @kriegaex, I want to match a single method 'someMethod'. By more generic I mean, If I try to target all methods of class, it works but I don't know how to match one and only one method whose definition is given above

Comment: But you do know! Your own example does just that. What is wrong with it? I thought you want to generalise in some way.

Comment: @kriegaex if my own example would have worked, I wouldn't have posted the question

Comment: Yes, it does, I have just tested it. Maybe your annotation has `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)` and thus is unavailable during runtime, maybe aspects are not working at all due to misconfiguration, I don't know. Maybe you have accidentally fixed the pointcut when editing it here and trying to anonymise the package, class and method names. ***But the pointcut is definitely correct.***

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys, let me prove that the pointcut actually works as written by the original poster *Haris Hasan*.

**Sample annotation:**

```java
package com.full.name.of;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SomeAnnotation {
    int id();
    String name();
}
```

**Sample class using the annotation:**

```
package com.full.name.of;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Class {
    @SomeAnnotation(id = 1, name = "John Doe")
    public void someMethod(Serializable s) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Class().someMethod("x");
    }
}
```

**Sample aspect with Haris Hasan's exact pointcut:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class SampleAspect {
    @Before("execution(@com.full.name.of.SomeAnnotation * com.full.name.of.Class.someMethod(java.io.Serializable))")
    public void yetAnotherPointcut(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
execution(void com.full.name.of.Class.someMethod(Serializable))
```

Copy and paste everything exactly as is, then run it. Quod erat demonstrandum.

Comment: thanks alot, my problem was that the someMethod was being invoked from within the class. AOP only works when method is invoked via proxy. I am changing my implementation accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Which lesson do we learn from this? Next time you seek help here, share more than just snippets, but a fully compileable and executable sample, optimally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). :-) BTW, if you want to intercept internal calls you cannot use proxy-based Spring AOP, you need to switch to full AspectJ. Spring manual, [Section 9.8, Using AspectJ with Spring applications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj), explains how to do that via load-time weaving.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not just use

```java
@Before("execution(* com.full.name.of.Class.someMethod(java.io.Serializable))")
```

That specifically targets the method you want, you do not need to put the annotation to specify the target

Comment: This does not work because it contains a syntax error. You need to specifiy at least a return type in the method signature, i.e. prepend `*` or `void`.

Comment: Added forgotten "*". I would like to take this opportunity to refer to SO guidelines on how to use downvoting:"Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.", and "Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases", "Instead of voting down If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it." An accidentally syntax error doesn't fit above criteria.Please respect the fact that some of us are not vote hunters,just people trying to help from personal time.Thank you

Comment: I respect your comment. Please note that I downvote not just everything which is not my own answer, maybe I perform 5-120 downvotes per month. I always consider the situation: We are dealing with an obvious AspectJ beginner here, so if you present him with a bogus, untested one-liner, he might not even be able to find out what is wrong. In this respect I think the downvote was deserved. And please respect the fact that I also do this in my sparetime, I am not a newbie here and have spent much more time helping people than you have - for free, just like you.

Comment: kriegaex thank you for explaining, I understand and do not disagree with what you write. However downvoting should be done on what SO thinks is deserved, and not what you or me thinks in order to have a global stable point of reference for downvoating. What I mean, is that according to SO a correction directly on my answer, or only the comment you made would be enough. I don't know if you get my point, but I recognise you do it in good feelings anyway

Comment: Listen, I saw this question and two answers, yours and Atul's. Both had syntax errors. You are right, I could have fixed both. But the two of you have not just posted bogus code, but also not read the question carefully, otherwise you would have noticed that the OP's question contained a pointcut which is already working(!) and does not need any alternatives. This is why I asked him what is actually the problem. Both your suggestion and Atul's solve a non-existent problem and make Hasan's own, working solution worse. Anyway, I will remove both downvotes after your fixes sparked by my comments.

Comment: I have also fixed your pointcut (there still was one double quote too many).

Answer (score 0):

The expression below should work:

<strike>`@Before("com.full.name.of.Class.someMethod(..) && args(java.io.Serializable)")`</strike>

*Correction by kriegaex:*

```java
@Before("execution(* com.full.name.of.Class.someMethod(*)) && args(java.io.Serializable)")
```

A few points worth considering: Is the method being advised public? Are you using cglib proxies or jdk proxies? Does your class implement any interface and is the method being advised declared in the interface contract?

Also do take a look at what spring doc has to say about [writing good pointcuts](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#writing-good-pointcuts)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not seem to make any sense. How can you bind an argument from a method signature with an empty parameter list?

Comment: @kriegaex modified the pointcut expression. This works. Tested.

Comment: @Atul, thanks, I will give it a try in a while will let you know

Comment: it gives error "error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut delete"

Comment: The pointcut syntax still has two errors: No pointcut type (such as `execution()` or `call()` is specified and no return type (such as `*` or `String`) is specified. @Atul: Don't give other people hints about how to write good pointcuts if you cannot even write a syntactically correct one after I told you how to correct it. I am going to fix your answer now.